# httpErrors defaultResponseMode ExecuteURL not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7, iis-8

I have this in my web.config:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" defaultResponseMode="ExecuteURL">
  <remove statusCode="404" />
  <error statusCode="404" path="/Error/NotFound" /> 
</httpErrors>
```

And when I browse for this URL (which does not exist): `http://localhost:8605/a.png` it does not execute my `NotFound` action in my `Error` controller. Why?

If I explicitely add `responseMode="ExecuteURL"` to the `error` element then it works.

Like so: `<error statusCode="404" path="/Error/NotFound responseMode="ExecuteURL" />`

Why can't I just set that attribute globally in the `httpErrors` element?

Comment: In both of your examples, you are missing the closing quote after your path value.  Try putting your quote in and see if that resolves anything

Comment: Sorry that was just a typo. Post updated.

Answer (score 0):

The **httpErrors defaultResponseMode** is not used for explicitly defined errors.

The [error documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms689487%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) signifies that the **error responseMode** default is **File**.

Comment: I found this to be true as well. Bad documentation to not call this out (if in fact it's by design). I would expect a DEFAULT parameter to be applied to all sub-parameters in a given section.